# Error al igualar valores de un array y operarlos

Tags: array, c

El caso es que tengo que calcular la media de varios alumnos <10 y estoy intentando operar la nota de los alumnos que (**será el resto resultante de dividir por 12 el valor obtenido de multiplicar por 10 el identificador del alumno por eso lo de x 10 %12 = nota**) y al hacer esto `lista[i].id * 10 % 12=lista[i].nota;`donde intento operar la posición del array y hacer la operación necesaria para igualar a las posiciones del array nota me da error.

**[Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment**

```
#include<stdio.h> 

struct alumno
{
    int id;
    float nota;
};

int main() {

int i;
int estudiantes;
float nota;
float media=0.0;
struct alumno lista[10];

printf("Introduzca un numero menor a 10 de estudiantes para analizar: ");
scanf("%d",&i);

while(0<estudiantes<10){
        for(i=0;i<=estudiantes;i++){
        lista[i].id=estudiantes++;
        lista[i].id * 10 % 12=lista[i].nota;
    }
    printf("LISTA DE ESTUDIANTES");
    printf("\n--------------------------------");
    printf ("\nEl numero de alumnos del conjunto es de %d.\n\n", i);
    
    for (i=0;i<=estudiantes;i++)
    {
      printf ("La nota del alumno [%d] es de %f.\n", lista[i].id,
          lista[i].nota);
    }
}       
getch ();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `0<estudiantes<10` Eso no hace lo que tu crees, tiene que ser `0<estudiantes && estudiantes<10`. Que es lo que se supone que quieres hacer aqui? `lista[i].id * 10 % 12=lista[i].nota;`.

Comment: Yo pondría while (estudiantes > 0 && estudiantes<10)

Comment: @Pablochaches ahí intento dar valor a las notas de los alumnos la cual sería igual al resto entre 12 por su ID multiplicada por 10

Comment: Y porque los pusiste en ese orden? Por el resto del código supongo que entiendes que lo que va del lado izquierdo del `=` recibe el valor, y lo que va del lado derecho lo da. Solo cambialos de lado y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con una variable extra que guarde el estado de lo que quieres guardar.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

struct alumno
{
    int id;
    float nota;
};

int main() {

int i;
int guarda;
int estudiantes;
float nota;
float media=0.0;
struct alumno lista[10];

printf("Introduzca un numero menor a 10 de estudiantes para analizar: ");
scanf("%d",&estudiantes);//me parece que aquí iría estudiantes porque usas i en los siguientes for inicializandolo de nuevo en 0.

while(0<estudiantes<10){ //nunca restas el valor de estudiantes dentro de while
        for(i=0;i>=estudiantes;i++){ //si vas de 0 al numero total sería mayor igual
        lista[i].id=estudiantes++;
        lista[i].id * 10 % 12=guarda;
        lista[i].nota = guarda
    }
    printf("LISTA DE ESTUDIANTES");
    printf("\n--------------------------------");
    printf ("\nEl numero de alumnos del conjunto es de %d.\n\n", i);
    
    for (i=0;i>=estudiantes;i++) //si vas de 0 al numero total sería mayor igual
    {
      printf ("La nota del alumno [%d] es de %f.\n", lista[i].id,
          lista[i].nota);
    }
  estudiantes--;
}       
getch ();
return 0;
}
```